# How to make a custom context menu in an Angular App?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I've been working on a custom context menu for a table on one of my views in an angular app. The idea is to display a hidden, absolutely-position div on right click of any particular row in this table.

I think the event is returning the correct `clientX` and `clientY`, but where I'm running into trouble is when I try to position this hidden div to the coordinates of the right-click event. What I'm using, right now, is this:

```
$('.toggled-options-status-change').css({
  top: event.clientX,
  left: event.clientY
}).show();
```

where `.toggled-options-status-change` is the class name of the hidden div.

What's basically happening is that the div is being position is seeming random spots, so it can't simply be fixed by decremented the top and left positions be constant values.

It's hard for me to tell what's going on, and I wish I could share a fiddle or something with you guys. What I'm hoping is that someone has come across an issue like this before and knows a direction to go and investigate further.

**Edit - CSS**

```
.toggled-options-status-change {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.off-canvas-wrap {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;

.inner-wrap {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 500ms ease;
  transition: transform 500ms ease;
}
```

**Edit - HTML**

*relevant html outline:*

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="off-canvas-wrap">
      <div class="inner-wrap">
        <div ng-view>
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you post the css corresponding to the `toggled-options-status-change` class?

Comment: Is this element in the root of the body? If not any positioned elements that are ancestors will cause it to not be positioned correctly. Please show all relevant code .. event handler and html outline structure

Comment: No, it's not. It has a few layers above it. I'll post a relevant outline in the OP. Yeah, because it's an angular app, this div is tucked away inside a partial tucked away inside **ng-view**

Comment: I'm wondering now if Foundation's `.inner-wrap` and `.off-canvas-wrap` affect position? I suppose they enlarge the body? I'll have to look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Almost always with these sorts of things, for me at least, the answer is exceedingly simple and makes me look like a fool for missing it the first time around. Oh well, it's nice to figure it out regardless.

*top should be clientY, not clientX, and vice versa.* omg